# install graphite +statsd ....getting error unknown carbon-cache

Tags: graphite, statsd

I am following these instructions(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-graphite-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server)
 to install statsd and graphite, but am running into below stated problem. Seems like this is not a graphite issue but python issue. Does anybody know how to resolve this?

```
~/build > sudo service carbon-cache start
 * Starting Graphite backend daemon carbon-cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/carbon-cache", line 32, in <module>
    run_twistd_plugin(__file__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/carbon/util.py", line 90, in run_twistd_plugin
    config.parseOptions(twistd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 604, in parseOptions
    usage.Options.parseOptions(self, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/usage.py", line 269, in parseOptions
    raise UsageError("Unknown command: %s" % sub)
twisted.python.usage.UsageError: Unknown command: carbon-cache
```

Comment: thanks sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: This bug is documented here a little but still can not find the solution http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2014-07/msg06664.html

Comment: What instructions are you following, and do they require Python 3? I did a quick search and saw instructions that referenced `python3.2`.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 ..is there a way i can point it to python 3?

Comment: That's out of scope for this question, but [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/440114/ubuntu-14-04-python-2-7-still-default-set-3-x-as-default/440126#440126) could help you point to python 3 (assuming it's installed).

Comment: no since i am using python 2.7 i do not want to acutally switch .. but just wanted to check if i could point graphite to python 3 ( in case that was causing this error) .. in the instructions i do not see that i need to use python 3 though .. so i am assuming something else is wrong

Answer (score 20):

I was following the same instructions and encountered the same problem.

Moving or removing the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted` directory also resolved the issue for me.

You can use for example the following command to change the name of the problematic directory:

```
mv /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted2
```

Then use `sudo service carbon-cache start` again

**Background**

I had the same issue on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Some investigation indicates that there are two virtually identical areas for twisted plugins on my machine.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted
```

and

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted
```

I am not sure where these two areas originate from. Perhaps one comes with the distro and the other is created through a manual `pip install twisted` that I may have done at one time. I suspect that the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` area gets populated with content when I install packages using `pip`. So this problem my eventually be attributed to users (e.g. me) installing `twisted` via `pip` and via the `apt` package system.

In any case, a diff through these areas showed that the carbon related files were installed into the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` area. `dpkg -L graphite-carbon` also indicates that the package files go into the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` area.

However, when the carbon start script is run is appears that `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/plugins` area is used leading to the plugin not being found.

I assume that this issue is related to the modules search path. As can be seen below the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` comes before the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` in my default path.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', 
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
>>>
```

Comment: good to know the solution helped! can you upvote my asnwer please?

Answer (score 12):

for some reason twisted was messing up something with graphite. 
read on the internet that manually removng twisted solves the problem. 
Tried it and it works now

just did

```
 sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twiste*
```

Comment: This worked. However, remember kids, before doing an `rm -rf` from some user2574872 dude on the internet, you should check if this is what you truly want.

Comment: 'pip uninstall twisted' did the thing for me, which incidently removes exactly these files..